# Android studio change password

Tags: php, java, android, android-studio

Estoy realizando un formulario de cambio de contraseña con android studio, php y mysql pero cuando doy click en el botón de cambio de contraseña sale un error, adjunto código php, java de android studio y fotografía del error.

Código PHP

```
        <?php
    require_once 'connect.php';
    $AntiguaContrasena = $_POST['antiguacontrasena'];
    $NuevaContrasena = $_POST['nuevacontrasena'];
    $ConfirmarContrasena = $_POST['confirmarcontrasena'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE contrasena = '$AntiguaContrasena' AND email = '$Email'";

    $query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    if ($NuevaContrasena == $ConfirmarContrasena) {
    if (!mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        echo "La contraseña anterior no coincide";
    }else{
        $update = "UPDATE alumnos SET contrasena = '$NuevaContrasena' WHERE email = '$Email'";
        $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$update);
        if ($res) {
            echo "La contraseña se ha cambiado correctamente";
        }else{
            echo "Error 101";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "Las contraseñas no son iguales";
}
?>
```

Código Java

```
btn_contrasena.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

            View cambiarcontraseñalayout = LayoutInflater.from(HomeActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_contrasena, null);
            EditText AntiguaContrasena = cambiarcontraseñalayout.findViewById(R.id.antiguacontrasena);
            EditText NuevaContrasena = cambiarcontraseñalayout.findViewById(R.id.nuevacontrasena);
            EditText ConfirmarContrasena = cambiarcontraseñalayout.findViewById(R.id.confirmarcontrasena);


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
            builder.setView(cambiarcontraseñalayout);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Cambiar Contraseña", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                    String antiguacontrasena = AntiguaContrasena.getText().toString().trim();
                    String nuevacontrasena = NuevaContrasena.getText().toString().trim();
                    String confirmarcontrasena = ConfirmarContrasena.getText().toString().trim();

                    if (antiguacontrasena.isEmpty() || nuevacontrasena.isEmpty() || confirmarcontrasena.isEmpty()) {
                        message("Algunos campos están vacíos");
                    } else {
                        progressDialog.show();
                        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_CONTRASENA, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                message(response);
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                message(error.getMessage());
                            }
                        }) {
                            protected Map<String, String> getParam() throws AuthFailureError {
                                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                                params.put("antiguacontrasena", antiguacontrasena);
                                params.put("nuevacontrasena", nuevacontrasena);
                                params.put("confirmarcontrasena", confirmarcontrasena);
                                params.put("email", stEmail);
                                return params;
                            }
                        };
                        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(HomeActivity.this);
                        queue.add(stringRequest);
                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

..............................................................................
Este es el error que aparece al dar click en el botón cambiar contraseña, ya revise las variables pero están bien, de ante mano gracias por su ayuda.

Error

Warning: Undefined array key "antiguacontrasena" in C:\xampp\htdocs\android\cambiodecontrasena.php on line 3

Warning: Undefined array key "nuevacontrasena" in C:\xampp\htdocs\android\cambiodecontrasena.php on line 4

Warning: Undefined array key "confirmarcontrasena" in C:\xampp\htdocs\android\cambiodecontrasena.php on line 5

Warning: Undefined array key "email" in C:\xampp\htdocs\android\cambiodecontrasena.php on line 6
La contraseña anterior no coincide

Comment: Mejor si copias el código y no agregas imagenes que dificultan leer el código. Yo de buenas a primeras creo que en el archivo php en la línea 9 te faltan las comillas ' '  en la variable $AntiguaContrasena.

Answer (score 0):

aunque hace poco que programo en android y menos en php prueba con este código la línia if($_SERVER... permite comprobar si existen variables POST y el tipo de dato que se espera

```
  require_once 'connect.php';

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        
      $AntiguaContrasena = $_POST['antiguacontrasena'];
      $NuevaContrasena = $_POST['nuevacontrasena'];
      $ConfirmarContrasena = $_POST['confirmarcontrasena'];
      $Email = $_POST['email'];

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE contrasena = '$AntiguaContrasena' AND email = '$Email'";

      $query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
      if ($NuevaContrasena == $ConfirmarContrasena) {
          if (!mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
               echo "La contraseña anterior no coincide";
          }else{
               $update = "UPDATE alumnos SET contrasena = '$NuevaContrasena' WHERE email = '$Email'";
               $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$update);
               if ($res) {
                    echo "La contraseña se ha cambiado correctamente";
               }else{
                    echo "Error 101";
               }
          }
      }else{
          echo "Las contraseñas no son iguales";
      } 
  }
```

Espero que te sirva.